# Understanding SAM3x8e boot program. Misunderstanding the datasheet

Tags: arduino-due

I'm trying to make my own firmware uploader for the Arduino DUE by using an ESP32.

While reading through the datasheet I saw that once there's data transmitted over the UART port, the sam3x8e will go into the SAM-BA monitor mode. The flowchart that the datasheet provides is as follow:
[image]

How does this make sense, since you can obviously communciate with the DUE over UART?
Do you have to avoid certain hex combinations, or does it get out of this loop automatically?

Comment: As far as I remember, it starts if the Flash memory is erased (by holding ERASE input pin low for more than about 250ms). And for example STM32 chips are controlled by BOOT0/BOOT1 input pins to run from bootloader section or flash section or even from RAM

Comment: There is a setting in flash that controls whether to boot from flash or to boot from ROM. When you erase the chip it defaults it to ROM.  When you program the chip you (usually) set that setting to boot from flash.